# Nested list back button sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

I need to **get value of back button** in nested list sencha touch 2 .. but it returns only back because it set default to back .. **is there any way to get the actual value of it ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working with the following code:

```
nestedlist.getBackButton().getText()
```

Answer (score 2):

Under `navigationview`, you have a property called as `defaultBackButtonText` which is used to set the default text for `back` button.

You can provide with your own text like this,

```
.....
defaultBackButtonText: 'PopView',
.....
```

To get the value of this text, you can simply make the below call ...

```
// Returns 'PopView'
navigationView.getDefaultBackButtonText();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
`useTitleAsBackText: true`